# Генератор множества

Tags: python, python-3.x, генераторы

Всем добрый вечер, стоит задача: Сгенерируйте множество уникальных значений от 8 до 50 включительно. Если элемент делится на 5, замените его на единицу, остальные оставьте как есть. Результат положите в generated_set. Тип переменной должен быть - set. Код такой:

```
generated_set = {x if x%5==0 else x==1 for x in range(8, 51)}
generated_set
```

> ```
> {False, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50}
> ```

Но это же неверно. Подскажите, в чем ошибся?
Мне кажется ответ должен быть таким:

```
{8, 9, 1, 11,..48, 49, 1}
```

Comment: `x%5==0` -> `x % 5 != 0`. `x==1` -> `1`.

Comment: не получается, тогда нет замены чисел, кратных 5 на 1, их просто нет

Comment: Получается, замена есть. Проверьте ещё раз, запустите код.

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос какой результат вы ожидаете.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```py
generated_set = {1 if x % 5 == 0 else x for x in range(8, 51)}
```

Comment: Спасибо, опять не получается, множество начинается с 1, а далее убираются все числа, кратные 5 {1, 8, 9, 11, ...48, 49} Это неверно. Всю голову сломал

Comment: Это из вопроса: "Если элемент делится на 5, замените его на единицу".

Comment: @АлексейМугуев Неповторяемость элементов - есть свойство множеств python. Более того, дополнительно указана информация об "уникальности значений" в самом задании.

Answer (score 3):

Про то, что условие проверки должно быть противоположное, вам уже написали. А вот по поводу пропадающих чисел - прочитайте, что такое "множество". В множестве числа не могут повторяться, так же как и ключи в словаре. Если числа повторяются, из одинаковых остаётся только первое. Поэтому результат `{8, 9, 1, 11,..48, 49, 1}` с повторяющимися числами в множестве невозможен. Проверим на простейшем примере:

```
print({8, 9, 1, 11, 48, 49, 1})
```

Вывод:

```
{1, 8, 9, 11, 48, 49}
```

Как видите, вторая единица исчезла из множества, хотя явным образом была там указана. Что вы и наблюдаете. При генерации единица есть, но когда формируется итоговое множество все повторные элементы из него пропадают.

Comment: Спасибо, теперь понял свою ошибку!!